# Can a Spring Boot standalone application integrated with Camunda consume JMS messages from JbossFuse?

Tags: spring-boot, jbossfuse, camunda

I have a activemq:queue inQueue in my JbossFuse. How do I consume those JMS messages which are enqueued so that my process instance is triggered in the Spring boot application integrated with Camunda ? Any link to references or samples would be helpful ?

Currently I am able to consume messages from activemq but I am not sure how to consume the messages from Jboss Fuse ActiveMQ ?

```
@Component
public class ActiveMQConsumer {

@Autowired
CamelContext camelContext;
@Autowired
ProducerTemplate producerTemplate;

@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
@JmsListener(destination = "inQueue")
public void consumeMessage(JSONObject employeeRecord) throws Exception {

    if (employeeRecord instanceof JSONObject) {
        HashMap<String, Object> employeeRecordMap = (HashMap<String, Object>) employeeRecord.toMap();
        Exchange exchange = ExchangeBuilder.anExchange(camelContext).withBody(employeeRecordMap).build();
        HashMap<String, Object> employeeDetails = (HashMap<String, Object>) employeeRecordMap.get("employeeDetails");
        exchange.setProperty("CamundaBpmBusinessKey", employeeDetails.get("employeeADId"));
        producerTemplate.send("camunda-bpm:start?processDefinitionKey=camunda-camel-activeMQ", exchange);
    }
    }
}
```

application.properties

```
# activeMQ config
spring.activemq.broker-url=tcp://localhost:61616
spring.activemq.user=admin
spring.activemq.password=admin
```

Expected to consume messages from JbossFuse.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend using the maven archetype io.fabric8.archetypes spring-boot-camel-amq-archetype version 2.2.197.  This can be found:

```
Spring Boot example running a Camel route connecting to ActiveMQ
http://repo1.maven.org/maven2/
```

This will get you a nice sample project that has all of the Camel and Spring dependencies and some nice samples.